# Unable To Access ElasticSearch Server Hosted In AWS Private Subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, ssh

I have a ElasticSearch Server hosted in AWS in a private subnet in a VPC.
I want to access the Kibana url for the ElasticSearch server from locally, so that I can query the ElasticSearch database.
I am hosting a Bastion Host server in the public subnet of the same VPC and tried to access the ElasticSearch server by doing a SSH tunneling to Bastion server.
But I am not able to access the ElasticSearch server using SSH tunneling.
Any help is highly appreciated.